# How to handle hover on different element and change the images of different element by css only

Tags: java, jquery, css, less

How to handle hover on different element and change the images of different element by css only

For example, imagine that the image is use as background in "i", that we need to change to image when we mouse over on "div" on hover. And the element structure is ..
`div` 
`i`
`div`

i want to do this **purely in css** and not in jQuery and js....

Comment: simply write : `div:hover i { /* your css*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
div:hover i{
  background:url(imageURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
i {
background:url(1.png) no-repeat;
}
div:hover i
{background:url(2.png) no-repeat;
}
</style>
<body>
<div>
<i>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, No issue. Your problem will be solved as with CSS and HTML code..
Follow the following code

CSS and HTML Code here -

```
<html>
<title></title>
<style>
#div_background{
background-image:url('imgname.extension');
height:xyz;
width:xyz;

}

#div_background:hover{
background-image:url('imgname.extension');
height:xyz;
width:xyz;

}
</style>
 <body>
 <div id="div_background"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

you can edit this code according to your structure

It is 100% working code.. After checking it in ur system please select this post as answer...